# jQuery(document).width() that doesn't include "white space"

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Consider these two functions:

1. `jQuery(document).width()`
2. `jQuery(window).width()`

(1) gives you the width of the web page, and (2) gives you the width of the browser viewport, roughly speaking.

But let's say we have a web page that is 800 pixels wide.

If the browser window width is less than 800 pixels, method (1) always returns 800. This is good.

But if the browser window width is greater than 800 pixels, method (1) returns the same as (2), and NOT 800. So the value of (1) is dependent of the browser window. This is not good.

My question is: given that you can't control the browser window size, and the browser window width in most cases is greater than the web page width, how do I get the real web page width, using javascript/jquery?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to when you say "real web page width"? You want the window width? The document width? The body width?

Comment: have you tred jQuery('body').width() ?

Comment: To be more precise, by the "real web page width" I mean the minimum width where the browser doesn't add a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @Anji: Yes, I've tried that. Problem is that the body element's width also typically expands infinitely when increasing the browser window width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, browser adds scroll bars, when it cant render certain **block** in current window width.
So, if you have a fixed-width main content block (which I'd advise you to), you can get it's width - it will always stay the same.

```
<div id="content">
<!-- Main block -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
   width:800px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#content").width()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but the next question is: how do I determine what is the "main content block"? I don't know the HTML content in advance.

Comment: Well, look how it's done here on StackOverflow:
**All** the main content is in body > container > content block, which is centered and has fixed width of 960px

Comment: Exactly! So the question boils down to: How to I find this div so I can determine the width? I need a general solution because I don't know the HTML code in advance.

Comment: This is no *right* general solution. 
You can get all divs on page and try to find the one with greatest width attribute (which will certainly be the main block), but that's a hack.

Comment: Ok, but thanks anyway. Perhaps it's not possible in JS, so i'll need to render the HTML in a fake browser and determine the width there.

Comment: I know it's many months ago, but I'm flagging this as the answer because it was closest to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really get the question, but there are many ways of getting the width of any object, here are the most commonly used:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/WB6tT/)

Try adding some markup to that fiddle, and see if any of them get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that doesn't get me closer to the solution.

Comment: Well, I really still don't get it? You wan't the width of the actual content, or in other words the element containing the main content, without knowing what that element is, where it's placed, what it's named etc. You are going to have a hard time figuring that one out, and any solution will most likely be slow and not very good at all. What exactly do you need this for, since this is not commonly used (don't think I've ever seen this anywhere), there probably are other better solutions to the problem.

Comment: I understand your confusion. But think of it as a tracking script you insert on a random web page. It simply needs to figure out the width of the "main element" because it needs to know where the mouse is positioned relatively to the content.